# Ajax inline editing via search bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, search

Right so basically, I have a system that displays the users on my website. There's also an ajax search bar that allows me to type their a letter and it instantly brings me up names with that letter in it as I go. Right now my editing system is inline editing with html5 & ajax. I've come across a problem however that doesn't allow me to inline edit anything that shows up inside of the search, althought buttons and links work inside of it. There might be an error in the code or it's just the wrong approach at it.

Here is my function for search.php on a home.php:

```
    <script>
function search(string){
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("search").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "search.php?s="+string, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
</script>
```

Here is my ajax.php:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    //database settings
    include "classes/forms/config.php";
    foreach($_POST as $field_name => $val)
    {
        //clean post values
        $field_userid = strip_tags(trim($field_name));
        $val = strip_tags(trim(mysql_real_escape_string($val)));

        //from the fieldname:user_id we need to get user_id
        $split_data = explode(':', $field_userid);
        $user_id = $split_data[1];
        $field_name = $split_data[0];
        if(!empty($user_id) && !empty($field_name) && !empty($val))
        {
            //update the values
            mysql_query("UPDATE players SET $field_name = '$val' WHERE id = $user_id") or mysql_error();
            echo "Updated";
        } else {
            echo "Invalid Requests";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid Requests";
}
?>
```

Here is my inline editing function:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    //acknowledgement message
    var message_status = $("#status");
    $("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
        var field_userid = $(this).attr("id") ;
        var value = $(this).text() ;
        $.post('ajax.php' , field_userid + "=" + value, function(data){
            if(data != '')
            {
                message_status.show();
                message_status.text(data);
                //hide the message
                setTimeout(function(){message_status.hide()},1500);
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

and finally my search.php:

```
    <?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
    <?php include_once('classes/check.class.php'); ?>
    <?php include('classes/forms/connect-db.php'); ?>
    <?php include('classes/functions.php'); ?>
    <?php include("classes/forms/config.php"); ?>
    <style>
    #status {padding:10px;font-weight:bold;font-size:24px;margin-bottom:10px;display:none;width:50%;background-color:#dff0d8;border-color:#d6e9c6;color:#468847;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        //acknowledgement message
        var message_status = $("#status");
        $("td[contenteditable=true]").blur(function(){
            var field_userid = $(this).attr("id") ;
            var value = $(this).text() ;
            $.post('ajax.php' , field_userid + "=" + value, function(data){
                if(data != '')
                {
                    message_status.show();
                    message_status.text(data);
                    //hide the message
                    setTimeout(function(){message_status.hide()},1500);
                }
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
    <?php echo "<div id='status'></div>"; ?>
    <?php


    if(isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s'] != ''){
        $s = $_GET['s'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE user LIKE '%$s%'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        echo " <div class='table-responsive'><table class='table'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Username</th> <th>Rank</th> <th>Position</th> <th>DoP</th> <th>Tag</th> <th>AiT</th> <th>Service Stripes</th> <th>Notes</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td id="user:'.$row['id'].'" contenteditable="true">' . $row['user'] . '</a></td>';
            echo '<td>'. member_rank($row['rank']) . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="position:'.$row['id'].'" contenteditable="true">' . $row['position'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="date:'.$row['id'].'" contenteditable="true">' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td id="notes:'.$row['id'].'" contenteditable="true">' . $row['notes'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="classes/forms/promote.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Promote</a><BR /><a href="classes/forms/demote.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Demote</a></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="classes/forms/delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="classes/forms/dd.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">DD</a><BR /><a href="classes/forms/hd.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">HD</a></td>';
            echo "</tr>"; 
        } 
        echo "</table> </div>";

    }

    ?>
```

The inline editing works perfect when I'm just going over the user, but like I stated before it won't work the search bar. The text doesn't update it just sits there and wait's for me to search for someone else  or refresh page.

Comment: Are there any errors showing in the browser's Inspector?

Comment: @rfornal no no errors are showing. It works perfectly fine, it just doesn't submit the info to mysql. It's basically like typing in a text box that doesn't submit.